# copy fields from one table to another in oracle toad

Tags: sql, oracle, copy, toad

I have a Table A with 5 columns in DEV env and I want to copy 3 columns from that table into an existing (truncated) table in TEST env. How can i do this using Toad in Oracle database?

Comment: insert into table1 (columns) .. select columns from table2

Comment: even though the 2 tables are in different environments?

Answer (score 0):

First create the database link. Following is the syntax :-

```
--Create database link
CREATE DATABASE LINK <dblinkname>
  CONNECT TO <username> IDENTIFIED BY <password> 
  USING '(DESCRIPTION=
  (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=<hostname>)(PORT=<port_no>))
  (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=<servicename>)))';
```

Now i will demonstrate this by giving you one example

```
 create table temp0
(
id number,
name varchar2(10)
);

--to be created in different environment
  create table temp00
  (
  id number,
  name varchar2(10)
  );

insert into temp00 values(1,'roy');
insert into temp00 values(2,'nick');
```

Now,

```
insert into temp0(id) select(id) from temp00@dblinkname; --this will insert all the values of id in temp0 table from temp00 table
```

Now depending on your requirement, you can insert whatever columns you want by passing column names